# can we specify user while logger object creation

Tags: python, logging

In python can we specify the user during the logger object creation?so that logger files gets created with that particular user permission always

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pwd
import grp
import os
import logging

logfile = 'my_file.txt'

# Create empty file
Path(logfile).touch()

# Set permissions
uid = pwd.getpwnam('some_user').pw_uid
gid = grp.getgrnam('some_group').gr_gid
os.chown(logfile, uid, gid)

# Write logs
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
```

Comment: I am already doing chown and it works. But my question is Does the python logger has flexibility of taking the user as input and create the logger files with that user instead of the current running user

Comment: according to the documentation this is not possible